# Why does C allow functions to return locally declared pointers but not locally declared arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, stack

Here, I have a function f() that locally defines an integer x and a pointer to it, pointer_x. And it returns that pointer. I then attempt to dereference the pointer, and it still gives me the correct integer that is pointed to by that pointer. My question is, if it is illegal for a function to locally declare an array and return that array (due to the deallocation of the stack frame as that function returns), why is it legal for a function to declare a pointer and return that pointer?

I am under the impression that an array is basically a pointer.

```
int *f();

int main(void){
    int *test;
    test = f();
    printf("%d", *test); //prints 0
}

int *f(){
    int x = 0; 
    int *pointer_x = &x;
    return pointer_x;
}
```

Comment: This code is broken, even if it seems working. Undefined behavior it is.

Comment: The compiler does not validate what a pointer is actually pointing at.  *In general*, returning a pointer is perfectly valid code, but returning a pointer that points at a local variable which goes out of scope when the function exits will return a *dangling pointer*, and dereferencing such a pointer is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: `f()` is weak code (UB).  C assumes the programmer is coding well and gives one all the rope they need to hang their own code.  It is **not**  legal for a function to declare a pointer (assigned to a local non-static object) and return that pointer

Comment: "an array is basically a pointer." is not the best view anymore than the houses in your neighborhood and the address of your house are not the same.

Comment: Or rather the sign pointing to the house... :D

Comment: I can't impress upon you how important it is to understand that "I am under the impression that an array is basically a pointer" is basically pointing in completely the wrong direction. Arrays and pointers are closely related, but an array is not a pointer and a pointer is not an array. It is crucial to understand when a pointer is a pointer and when an array is an array. C doesn't make it easy: you can write `int function(int array[SIZE]) { … }` and it looks like `array` is an array, but in the function it is a pointer rather than an array, for all you can use array subscripting to access it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler does it decay at that point?  Not relevant to the closed question but would sizeof not work correctly?  I NEVER use function prototypes like that, always a pointer and a sizeof param.

Comment: In addition to that, `[]` operator can only be applied to values that are of pointer type...

Comment: @Bwebb — yes, the “decay” happens and within the function, `sizeof(array) == sizeof(`int` *)`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That is not my coding style but its still good to know when reading other peoples code.  Thank you for confirming.  In my previous comment I meant something like *void func(int * arry, int len)*

Comment: @Bwebb: I just compiled a variant of the function with GCC 8.2.0 with no extra warnings enabled, and it said: `warning: ‘sizeof’ on array function parameter ‘array’ will return size of ‘int *’ [-Wsizeof-array-argument]` — `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(array));` — `ap31.c:5:26: note: declared here` — `static void function(int array[SIZE])`.  I get the same result with a VLA signature: `static void function(int size, int array[size]) { … }`.  Arrays in function signatures are treated like pointers.  See also C11 [§6.9.1 Function definitions ¶10](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p10), etc.

Comment: Note that `int *f(){ int *pointer_x = malloc(...);return pointer_x;}` would not be an error.

Comment: And see also C11 [§6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes) ¶7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p7): _A declaration of a parameter as ''array of type'' shall be adjusted to ''qualified pointer to type'', where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation._

Comment: @TimRandall: The problem is more 'returning pointers to (non-static) local variables' than 'returning locally declared pointers' — but your counter-example is good.